# Дубликаты стилей

Tags: css

Проблема заключается в том, что при просмотре кода сайта через инспектор, все стили всех элементов продублированы. Кеш и Куки чистил. Проблема наблюдается и в других браузерах.

Подскажите, почему такое происходит и как это излечить?

ссылка удалена

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас 2 раза подключается фаил стилей

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/template/default/r/style.css">
```

уберите 2е подключение и стили в режиме отладки дублироваться не будут

Comment: Спасибо!
Я еле нашел причину дублирования подключения,
опять моя невнимательность..

Comment: незачто, обращайтесь)